# the route app.post is not working for express

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I know this has been asked a lot but I cant find a solution for mine

my `package.json` is looking like so:

```
"main": "server.js",
```

server.js has

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('found the route');
})
```

why is it not logging found the route when I go to localhost:8000??

express is installed etc, just a very basic project

```
const port = 8000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Did you really sent a `POST` request to the route?!

Comment: How do you _go to localhost:8000_? `app.post` will catch POST method.

Comment: @AdamAzad see updated answer

Comment: @JonasW. well thats what im wondering

Comment: The updated answer doesn't add anything new. How do you test it? Add `app.get` for the same path. Either one will be caught--depending on REQUEST_METHOD

Comment: not sure what you mean. my added answer proves that everything is set up, but when i look at the server logs i get nothing for the route `/` or indeed any other route indicating post is not working

Comment: you can test it with postman.

Comment: Add this line as well. `app.get('/', () => console.log('GET on /'))`

Comment: also testing it in postman and it says cannot GET /

Comment: @TheDecimator GET !== POST

Comment: that console.log correctly logs,...

Comment: @bee what else do you want to see, it's one file with express stuff, a couple of nodemodules, packagejson, thats it...

Comment: try this ->  app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

Comment: I see hello world in the browser..

Comment: isn't this what you were trying to do or what were you looking to do?

Comment: im following a tutorial (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2) and he is using post requests

Comment: just wondering why when following this, it wasn't working

Comment: ok it is working now, thanks for the help